# How would you do ternary conditionals inside {%%} in Twig

Tags: php, twig, bolt-cms

I want to render parameters if they exist but can't find a way of correctly displaying it and keep getting 
*An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ")")*

where

```
{% setcontent records = 'properties' where
{filter:search_term,
((classification) ? ('classification':classification):(''))
} printquery  %}
```

Comment: what you expect  with this code `('classification':classification)` ?

Comment: Sorry to render **'classification':classification**  if it classification variable exists

Answer (score 2):

To use it inside `Bolt CMS`, first define your options and then pass that to `Bolt CMS`

```
{% set options = { filter: search_term , } %}
{% if classification is defined and classification|trim != '' %}
    {% set options = options|merge({classification:classification,}) %}
{% endif %}

{% setcontent records = 'properties' where options printquery  %}
```

---

<s>After rereading your question you are probably looking for something like this,</s>

```
{% set records %}
'properties' where { 
    filter : '{{ search_term }}',
    classification: '{{ classification is defined ? classification : '' }}',
} printquery  %}
{% endset %}

{{ records }}
```

However using the filter [`default`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html) here is more suited than using the ternary operator,

```
{% set records %}
'properties' where { 
    filter : '{{ search_term }}',
    classification: '{{ classification|default('') }}',
} printquery  %}
{% endset %}

{{ records }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/6wzrpv)

---

To omit properties you would use the following,

```
{% set records %}
'properties' where { 
    filter : '{{ search_term }}',
    {% if classification is defined and classification|trim != '' %}classification: '{{ classification }}',{% endif %}
} printquery  %}
{% endset %}
```

Comment: Thank you its much clear. But I wanted to see if i could do

`classification: '{{ classification|default('') }}`

But as
`{{classification:classification|default('') }}`

Comment: No, because the `:` is used in created arrays e.g, `{% set foo = { classification: classifcation|default(''), } %}`

Comment: Ok, I've tried the same. But since if var `classification` doesnt exists if becomes empty, my bolt query will search for  ``bolt_properties`.`classification` = ''` which will return empty. Thus i wanted to search by classification if it exists as a get param

Comment: See editted answer if you want to omit non-existing/empty filters

Comment: Thank you. I just checked i'm using Bolt CMS. I cant query using {%set%} but only {%setcontent%}

Comment: See last edit - Did not know `{% setcontent ..` was a valid node

Comment: Thank you! it makes sense now.